# Google Adwords conversions with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, google-ads-api, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost newsletter that has a premium subscription set up with Stripe.

Basically, people go to the `/subscribe` page, choose a price, get redirected to Stripe, and then upon success, get redirected to the main page `/`, where the url will now have this appended:

`?stripe_portal=success`

I want to track Google Adwords conversions when the purchase is made.

I don't know how to do that, as conversion code on the main page would also count normal visits.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not really a Stripe integration question, you could have the post-subscription landing page be a distinct URL where you track this, then redirect back to your home page if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Add this conditional JavaScript to your main page:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
if (params.get('stripe_portal') === "success") {
  // track conversion
}
```